Fail to install waferslim
I used fitnesse extensively before.  I am trying to use it for my python test.  However, I have trouble to install waferslim to Windows 11 from https://pypi.org/project/waferslim/.
First, pip failed:
$ pip install waferslim
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement waferslim (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for waferslim
$ python --version
Python 3.11.9
$ pip --version
pip 24.0 from C:\Users\Cheng\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)

I have downloaded waferslim-1.0.2-py3.1.zip from https://pypi.org/project/waferslim/#files. It contains no requirement.txt.  I wonder if it is the reason why pip fails.
Second, direct installation fails. From the README of the downloaded zip file:
To install waferslim as a site-package run (from this directory) 
 python3 setup.py install 

Even logged in as admin, I still get the following errors
$ python setup.py install
running install
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib\\site-packages\\test-easy-install-20500.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:
    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

Is the failure because waferslim is too old (3.1 vs 3.11)?
Is there any alternative for fitnesse slim test for python?

Waferslim explicitly says it only supports python up to 3.1 so pip on 3.11 wont be able to install it because of that.

@rasjani  Thanks!  Does that mean I should give up fitnesse, unless I want to port waferslim to 3.11?

it could be that the code actually works 3.11, its just the setup.py that sets up the medatata that says 3.1 is the newest..  Just download the source archive and try out.
